# NumPy: filter rows by np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to filter a NumPy 2-d array by checking whether another array contains a column value. How can I do that?

```
import numpy as np

ar = np.array([[1,2],[3,-5],[6,-15],[10,7]])
another_ar = np.array([1,6])
new_ar = ar[ar[:,0] in another_ar]
print new_ar
```

I hope to get `[[1,2],[6,-15]]` but above code prints just `[1,2]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html),but note that as `ar[:,0]` is a list of first elements if `ar` you need to loop over it and check for membership :

```
>>> ar[np.where([i in another_ar for i in ar[:,0]])]
array([[  1,   2],
       [  6, -15]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `in`, you can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to check which values in the first column of `ar` are also in `another_ar` and then use the boolean index returned to fetch the rows of `ar`:

```
>>> ar[np.in1d(ar[:,0], another_ar)]
array([[  1,   2],
       [  6, -15]])
```

This is likely to be much faster than using any kind of `for` loop and testing  membership with `in`.